# Terraform has detected that the configuration specified for the backend has changed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, backend, state-management

**TL;DR:** I have accidentally deployed via `terraform` to multiple regions using back-end state management in multiple regions. Now I want to clean it all up with `terraform`. Is this possible? How should I approach the problem?

A few months ago I created a solution which I pushed to `AWS` via `terraform`, using back-end state management with `S3` and `dynamo table lock`. It deployed successfully, but upon returning to it recently I have discovered that I had apparently changed both the `terraform init` back-end parameters and the `provider` region values between deployments.

What I believe I was left with, back then, was two separate deployments - one in one region and one in another. The problem, now, is that I'm not sure which region's state is used to manage which region's resources.

My documented `terraform init` is setup to use `us-east-1` to manage back-end state. Looking at the versioning of the `.tf` files, I can see that at some point I had resources deployed to `eu-central-1`. I don't know if I have erroneously deployed to one region while managing state in another, but I suspect so.

In an attempt to destroy the `eu-central-1` resources, I have run the below `init` locally. The result below is what followed.

```
> terraform init -backend-config="bucket=app-us-east-1-lambda-state" -backend-config="key=modules/app-lambda-function/terraform.tfstate" -backend-config="region=us-east-1" -backend-config="dynamodb_table=app-us-east-1-lambda-lock"
Initializing modules...

Initializing the backend...
Backend configuration changed!

Terraform has detected that the configuration specified for the backend
has changed. Terraform will now check for existing state in the backends.


Acquiring state lock. This may take a few moments...
Acquiring state lock. This may take a few moments...
Do you want to copy existing state to the new backend?
  Pre-existing state was found while migrating the previous "s3" backend to the
  newly configured "s3" backend. An existing non-empty state already exists in
  the new backend. The two states have been saved to temporary files that will be
  removed after responding to this query.

  Previous (type "s3"): C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\terraform123456798\1-s3.tfstate
  New      (type "s3"): C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\terraform123456789\2-s3.tfstate

  Do you want to overwrite the state in the new backend with the previous state?
  Enter "yes" to copy and "no" to start with the existing state in the newly
  configured "s3" backend.

  Enter a value:
```

Now, unfortunately (I suspect), at this point I typed `no`, hit return and the following is what happened...

```
  Enter a value: no

Releasing state lock. This may take a few moments...
Releasing state lock. This may take a few moments...

Successfully configured the backend "s3"! Terraform will automatically
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.

Initializing provider plugins...
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/archive from the dependency lock file
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/aws from the dependency lock file
- Using previously-installed hashicorp/archive v2.1.0
- Using previously-installed hashicorp/aws v3.30.0

Terraform has been successfully initialized!

You may now begin working with Terraform. Try running "terraform plan" to see
any changes that are required for your infrastructure. All Terraform commands
should now work.

If you ever set or change modules or backend configuration for Terraform,
rerun this command to reinitialize your working directory. If you forget, other
commands will detect it and remind you to do so if necessary.
```

At this point I tried to destroy the resources but this failed for various reasons. I have trimmed most of them, but what you see is a good example of them all...

```
> terraform destroy --auto-approve --var-file=../../local.tfvars
Acquiring state lock. This may take a few moments...

Error: error deleting CloudWatch Events Rule (my-app-rule): ValidationException: Rule can't be deleted since it has targets.
        status code: 400, request id: 1234567-1234-1234-1234-12345679012
```

So what I believe I have done in the past is:

1. Deploy with both back-end management and providers set to `eu-central-1`
2. Changed provider to `us-east-1` and re-deployed
3. Changed back-end management to `us-east-1` and re-deployed
4. More recently, changed the back-end management back to `eu-central-1` and attempted `destroy`

Now, I understand that this is all on my personal account and I can manually destroy all the resources using the console. However, I would like to understand what I should have done *when I realised* that (months ago) I had been repeatedly deploying while also changing the back-end and provider regions.